# "Invalid file format" from device pulled *.db file in Nexus 4 - Android 5.1.1

Tags: android, sqlite, pull

I'm learning Android developement. And I receive always this error while opening a pulled database file from device: "Invalid file format"

I use this commands to pull the

```
adb shell "run-as package chmod 666 /data/data/package/files/database"
adb exec-out run-as package cat files/database > C://test/database
```

I thik, the file size is correct, and when I open it in with a text editor I can read the content, with special characters, of course. But the sqliteBrowser can't read it.

Comment: Surely there's a better way to download files other than `cat`?

Comment: I have already  solved it!
`adb -d shell "run-as com.package cat /data/data/com.package/files/database.db > /sdcard/database.db"`

And then I can copy manually (with the windows explorer) from the scard. Thx

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem with android 4.2, although I used ubuntu 16.04 and sqlite browser instead.

I found only one way that I could access my not rooted phone's file system and finally I could open the database file.

[Install SSHDroid on your phone](https://www.maketecheasier.com/access-android-device-with-linux-file-managers/)

```
adb -d shell "run-as your.package.name cat databases/database_name.db > /mnt/sdcard/database_name.db"
```

just for sure, you can check whether the file is there

```
$ adb shell
shell@android:/ $ cd /mnt/sdcard
shell@android:/mnt/sdcard $ ls
```

if you don't know the exact name of your package then

```
adb shell 'pm list packages -f'
```

start the `SSHDroid`

the default username is `root` and the default password is `admin`. It makes sense to change the password.

[image: SSHDroid setting]

start `FileZilla`
open the `Site Manager` and add a `new site` with the settings of the SSHDroid's ssh server.

[image: FileZilla's Site Manager]

set `/mnt/sdcard` as default remote directory

[image: set the default remote directory]

and connect to your phone via SFTP protocol

[image: your phone's filesystem in FileZilla]